# How to capture just owner value of a folder using batch script on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to capture the owner value of a folder in windows 2008 server using batch script. I was able to capture this information using PowerShell script, but unfortunately given the current situation, PowerShell is not an option on the table and I am researching to figure out how to do it using batch script.

I have tried this so far and it is not giving me what I want, is there another way to achieve this?

```
set "foldername=c:\temp"
set "owner="

for /f "tokens=5*" %%i in ('dir /q %foldername%') do if not defined owner set "owner=%%i"
echo %owner%
```

Here is the output, but not all values are accurate, some are capturing owner, but some values for owner have wrong information

> C:>getowner.bat
>
> C:>set "foldername=c:\temp"
>
> C:>set "owner="
>
> C:>for /F "tokens=5*" %i in ('dir /q c:\temp') do if not defined
>   owner set "owner=%i"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=has"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=421B-3AFF"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=NT"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=BUILTIN\Administrators"
>
> C:>if not defined owner set "owner=free"

I am looking to see if there is any other better alternative where I am not trying to parse a string to find this info.

**Update**: The above script must be executed remotely.

I will really appreciate for providing me the correct direction.

-Jb

Comment: As far as I'm aware `PowerShell 2.0` is part of `Windows Server 2008`, so running it, even directly from a batch file should not be an issue. If I recall correctly the Integrated Scripting Environment, `PowerShell_ISE`, may be an optional feature to enable, but that isn't necessary for your purpose.

Comment: @Compo Running the PowerShell script remotely is giving me kerberos authentication error and given the security guidelines at our place I am not allowed to make changes in that regard.

Comment: I never said that you wouldn't have issues running a `PowerShell` script, I stated only that `PowerShell 2.0` was part of that OS and suggested only that you could run `PowerShell` from a batch file, _(as can be clearly noted in lit's answer)_.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion, just explaining that I already went thru that avenue and finally stopped after hitting the Kerberos roadblock.

Comment: The only way I could have known your reason(s) was to make my comment, because you clearly did not mention it, despite it technically being a more appropriate question. _(e.g. I have a, usually, working PowerShell script which is producing a kerberos authentication error on Windows 2008 Server when executed remotely…)_

Comment: jb ... Have you tried below mentioned solution by @Squashman and see if works remotely? Just curious

Comment: I am going to give that a try and post an update here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using a fully qualified path, if you look for a space and dot at the end of the output line you will get the correct owner of the folder because the DIR command is actually looking inside the temp folder.

```
@echo off
set "foldername=c:\temp"
set "owner="
for /f "tokens=5* delims= " %%i in ('dir /ad /q c:\temp ^|findstr /R /C:" \.$"') do set "owner=%%i"
echo %owner%
pause
```

Adding in a second option that uses WMIC that is listed over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1103541/774709)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Escpe the backslash with \\
SET foldername=C:\temp
SET foldername=!foldername:\=\\!

wmic path Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting where Path="!foldername!" ASSOC /RESULTROLE:Owner /ASSOCCLASS:Win32_LogicalFileOwner /RESULTCLASS:Win32_SID > "%temp%\wmi.tmp"

for /F "skip=2 delims=€" %%G in ('type %temp%\wmi.tmp') do (call :process_wmioutput "%%G")

pause
goto :EOF

:process_wmioutput
SET UNDELIMITED=%1
SET DELIMITED=!UNDELIMITED:  =€!
FOR /F "delims=€ tokens=10,12" %%G in ("!DELIMITED!") DO (ECHO %%H\%%G)
exit /B
```

Comment: The output field size in the DIR command is not always long enough to contain the full owner name.

Comment: @squashman, your solution is working based on my question. I am accepting your answer. If I try the same solution for a folder under "c:\program files", it does not work. I am assuming some additional security might be preventing it. Going to troubleshoot further to see why... If you know the reason, I will be very glad to know why..Thank you.

Comment: @jbl, yes the first set of code has a side affect that lit pointed out in his comment. The length of the owner runs into the actual folder name so the default delimiter of a space does not work. A possible fix for that would be to also use a period as a delimiter. The second set of code works correctly.

Comment: @jbl, this might work better. https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/folderOwner.bat

Comment: I finally was able to get your WMIC solution working with Program files folder. I had to pass the parameter inside double quotes and then strip it off inside. I am going to take a peek at fileutils link you have suggested as well. I am new to batch scripting syntax, learning as I go... appreciate all the support

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to get the owner. Note that the OWNER variable will be set for the last directory. I am not sure if that is what is needed.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "FOLDERNAME=C:\temp"
SET "OWNER="
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (`powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path "%FOLDERNAME%" |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "if ($_.PSIsContainer) { ($_.GetAccessControl()).Owner }" ^
        "}"`) DO (SET "OWNER=%%~i")
ECHO %OWNER%
```

Comment: He did say no Powershell.

Comment: @Squashman - Sorry, I missed that. I wonder if the OP knows that the PowerShell executable can be run from a .bat file script? I think this is what Compo's comment is about.

Comment: Correct @lit, the OP didn't specify the reason why `PowerShell` was not on the table, because it is installed on the OS. I am aware that running `PowerShell` scripts may mean be problematic due to policy/security issues and was simply informing them that it may not be off the table!